# WinIdea/TestIdea, changing the value of a variable with a python script does not work

Tags: python, testing, system-testing

I don't know if you hear about isystems tools but I'm working with these, TestIdea/WinIdea. I wrote a scripts in Python, to change the value of a sensor ( 30 times ) and I need to monitor how it is his behavior. I put a test point, with the execution of my function on the line that I need. But the value of that variable still remain 0 if I only use the script but If I assign a value manually of that variable it's working. So I think the function and the line of his are good but I don't know what it's wrong. This is the code and is good because I have output:

```
def SawTooth(self):

    Rte_IoHwAb_IoHwAbSRSendSpoolSenseADCPort_IoHwAbDataElement = 0
    for i in range(31):
        if Rte_IoHwAb_IoHwAbSRSendSpoolSenseADCPort_IoHwAbDataElement < 4.5:
            Rte_IoHwAb_IoHwAbSRSendSpoolSenseADCPort_IoHwAbDataElement = Rte_IoHwAb_IoHwAbSRSendSpoolSenseADCPort_IoHwAbDataElement + 0.5
        else:
            Rte_IoHwAb_IoHwAbSRSendSpoolSenseADCPort_IoHwAbDataElement = 0.5


        print(i,Rte_IoHwAb_IoHwAbSRSendSpoolSenseADCPort_IoHwAbDataElement)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB45U.png

And if I put the same line in which to execute the test point and finish the test, it enters a fine loop and the program goes continuously without stopping.

I don't know If anybody can help me without the source code but I said to try my luck :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you would like to change the value of a variable that resides in your target application. These target variables can be accessed with an instance of isystem.connect class CTestCaseController. Use *modify()* to assign new values and *evaluate()* to read the current value of your variable.

Assuming that your target variable is named identical to the one in your script:

```
    def SawTooth(self):
    if self.testCtrl == None:
        self.testCtrl = ic.CTestCaseController(self.connectionMgr, self._isys_testCaseHandle)
        
    Rte_IoHwAb_IoHwAbSRSendSpoolSenseADCPort_IoHwAbDataElement = 0
    for i in range(31):
        if Rte_IoHwAb_IoHwAbSRSendSpoolSenseADCPort_IoHwAbDataElement < 4.5:
            Rte_IoHwAb_IoHwAbSRSendSpoolSenseADCPort_IoHwAbDataElement = Rte_IoHwAb_IoHwAbSRSendSpoolSenseADCPort_IoHwAbDataElement + 0.5
        else:
            Rte_IoHwAb_IoHwAbSRSendSpoolSenseADCPort_IoHwAbDataElement = 0.5
            
        self.testCtrl.modify('Rte_IoHwAb_IoHwAbSRSendSpoolSenseADCPort_IoHwAbDataElement', str(Rte_IoHwAb_IoHwAbSRSendSpoolSenseADCPort_IoHwAbDataElement))
        
        eval_value = self.testCtrl.evaluate("Rte_IoHwAb_IoHwAbSRSendSpoolSenseADCPort_IoHwAbDataElement,d")
        print(f"{i},{eval_value}")
```

I hope this will help you further. Best regards, Pim (iSystem Support)

Comment: Yes, I do it. But to problem now is I give that 30 times values but the calculation is only made at the end of the the tast case and I want to do it for all 30 variables, how to do it?